# SOAP Alerts for Team Foundation Service

Tags: wcf, soap, tfs, azure-devops

This question is probably very similar to 
[404 Error when TFS 2010 Sends SOAP Alert to a WCF 4.0 Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116851/404-error-when-tfs-2010-sends-soap-alert-to-a-wcf-4-0-service) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891773/subscribing-to-tfs-events-and-wcf)
 but I can not figure out where I went wrong. (So hoping that [Ewald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422565/ewald-hofman) will chime in)

I went through all the samples and questions that I could find, but somehow, I still do not get any alerts to come through.

My test implementation is deployed on azure and I configured my free tfs service (***.visualstudio.com) to actually post new work items to that endpoint.

When I create a client proxy myself, I can see the data arrive. So something must still be wrong in the code/configuration?

```
namespace Tfs.NotificationService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
    public interface INotifyService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
        void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml);
    }

    public class NotifyService : INotifyService
    {
        void INotifyService.Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml)
        {
            using (var db = new NotificationContext())
            {
                db.Notifications.Add(new Notification { EventXml = eventXml, TfsIdendityXml = tfsIdentityXml });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The web.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NotifyServiceBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NotifyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NotifyServiceBehavior" name="Tfs.NotificationService.NotifyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NotifyServiceBinding"
                  contract="Tfs.NotificationService.INotifyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Project is a ASP.Net MVC 4 - .Net 4.5 - with EF 5.0 to store the data.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but I have defined the Notify this way:    `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class TfsEventServices : ITfsEventServices` You could give it a try. Do you see any error messages why it fails to call the webservice? This can be checked in [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobHistory], after some logging settings were changed.

Comment: Mike: Excellent! That seems to do the trick. (ps: you should copy your comment to an answer, so I can mark it as such.)

Comment: @MikeR & Rudi, I'm having the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139632/does-visual-studio-online-support-soap-workitem-change-notification) Applying that to the class didn't resolve the issue for me.  I see nothing in the IIS logs that indicates that VSO is even trying to hit this service. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working solution:

```
namespace Tfs.NotificationService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
    public interface INotifyService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
        void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class NotifyService : INotifyService
    {
        void INotifyService.Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NotifyServiceBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NotifyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NotifyServiceBehavior" name="Tfs.NotificationService.NotifyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NotifyServiceBinding"
                  contract="Tfs.NotificationService.INotifyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```