# Does Visual Studio Online support SOAP WorkItem change notification?

Tags: wcf, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

The reason I ask, is that I've set up a WCF service following the guidance out there (specifics below), and set up a SOAP notification in Visual Studio Online and my service doesn't appear to be called.  IIS 8.5 Logs show no attempt to make contact with the service from VSO servers.

In case it IS supported, here are relevant bits to see if I have something set up wrong on the service side.

**WCF Service - .NET 4.5.1 hosted as an Azure WebRole**

Contract and Implementation

```csharp
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
public interface IWorkItemSubscriber
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
    void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml);
}

// Note, I've tried w/ and w/out this Compatibility Attribute
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WorkItemSubscriber : IWorkItemSubscriber
{
    public void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Web.Config

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="noSecurity">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="VsoNotificationService.Wcf.WorkItemSubscriber" behaviorConfiguration="eventServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="noSecurity" contract="VsoNotificationService.Wcf.IWorkItemSubscriber" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="eventServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> <!-- note: I've tried w/ and w/out the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute -->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Visual Studio Online Configuration**

[image: Screencap of VSO configuration]

I've confirmed I can hit the service, via creating my own client and calling the service.  Whatever code I put in the method is executed, and if I do remote debugging via Visual Studio 2013 I'll hit the method's breakpoint.  So the service is up and running, I just don't see traffic from Visual Studio Online (via code breakpoint, code content, nor IIS Logs).  Makes me think that feature is not working there?

Comment: Looks like a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861263/soap-alerts-for-team-foundation-service  -- But the suggestion there didn't help

Comment: Please use the following SQL statement on your TFS database: `SELECT  StartTime, Result, ResultMessage 
FROM [Tfs_ConfigDB].[dbo].[tbl_JobHistory]

WHERE JobId = 'A4804DCF-4BB6-4109-B61C-E59C2E8A9FF7'
AND Result <> 0`  It will list the notifications that got errors, maybe you will see something like webservice not available/reachable.

Comment: @MikeR, this is visual studio online -- as the subject/OP says, I don't have access to the database (that I am aware of...)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are missing the `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"` on the `<serviceHostingEnvironment` element, as compared to [my working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861263/soap-alerts-for-team-foundation-service), it might be the missing piece of the puzzle?

I only also achieved success by carefully including all little config settings.

Comment: I'll add that, see if it helps.  Like I said though, I'm not even seeing traffic from VSO servers...  Are you still running your system against Visual Studio Online?

Comment: No go.  Still not receiving hits from VSO.  IIS Log remains empty.